# Как найти первое встретившееся число в строке String и его длину?

Tags: java, строки

Дано строка: `"id { temp : 235235"` , число заранее не известно. Т.к. чисел в строке много, сначала нахожу индекс нужного поля - в данном случае "id". Далее необходимо найти индекс ближайшего к ниму числа или цифры, затем длину числа (для того чтобы его стереть и заменить на другое). Как это можно сделать, элегантнее, чем циклом с проверкой символа на знак "цифры"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ну по формату выглядит как json, ты можешь строку преобразовать в json если он не большой и просто идти по дереву пока не встретишься число
2. Просто регуляркой находишь через Pattern \D.+ первое число в строке, если надо через метод у строки indexOf находишь начальный индекс , ну это если надо

Comment: Спасибо! Так и сделал.